# Need to get events using a TicketMaster API with Axios and React.js

Tags: reactjs, axios

I have a react component with a zip code form and submit button. I need to use axios to pull with my TicketMaster api key and load all events within the zip code entered on the submit button click.

I know I need to do an axios.get() but don't know where or how to put it.

Here I have the state set:

```
class Menu extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
        events: [],
        postalCode: "",
        searchTerm: ""
    };
    console.log(this.state);
}
```

This is the form with the Zip Code and Submit button:

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
        <div className="panel panel-default" >
            <div className="panel-heading">
                <h3 className="panel-title">Menu</h3>
                <h2 className="panel-title">
                    Zip Code: <input
                        type="text"
                        name="zipCode"
                        value={this.state.event}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}
                    />
                </h2>
                <button
                    onClick={this.handleFormSubmit}
                    type="success"
                    className="input-lg"
                >Submit</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing a request in `handleFormSubmit`?

Answer (score 0):

Call you axios on handleFormSubmit